# pdf generation consuming lot of memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf + wicked_pdf to generate pdf. I am using sidekiq to background it.
Following is my configuration

```
pdf = render_to_string :pdf => pdf_request.file_name,
       :layout => "pdf.html",
       :template => "shared/report",
       :formats => [:pdf],
       :margin => {:top => 10, :bottom => 0},
       :disable_javascript => true
```

Once the html file is generated in the tmp folder, I see a sudden increase in memory.

For eg, I watched memory utilization while generating a pdf with 200k records(~3000 pages). Memory started to increase around 20MB per second after the html file was generated in the tmp files. I guess its the time when it actually writes to the pdf file. I keeps increasing and the process fails running out of memory.

My pdf has a table on each page with 70 rows.

Has any one else seen this behaviour? Is there anything I could do to reduce memory consumption?

Comment: What version of rails, wicked_pdf and wkhtmltopdf are you running?

Comment: `wkhtmltopdf - 0.9.6`, `wicked_pdf - 0.9.10`

Comment: Your wkhtmltopdf is relatively old. They fixed a bunch of memory issues since then. Is upgrading to 0.12.0 an option?

Comment: @H-man: yes. I will try upgrading

Comment: @H-man: I tried using 0.12.0. It definitely is better than 0.9.6. I can generate 200k records now. But when I try to generate 400k, it fails with segmentation fault.

Comment: Is it the same error as 200k records with 0.9.6?

Comment: @H-man: yes. It slowly runs out of memory and i get the same error

Comment: I'm out of ideas, I'm sorry. I'd play with the options, like use `:lowquality => true`, `:grayscale => true` or something and see if that fixes it. Also, simplifying the generated HTML markup might improve the performance.

Comment: How did you get this working with Sidekiq out of curiousity. I definitely want to set that up! Love both gems, but WickedPDF is a wicked server hammer when it runs :-)

Comment: @JohnTrichereau To generate PDFs in a job queue like Sidekiq, check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/25038875/23915